# Laravel changing url name

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So I'm using the laravel `auth` because I wanted to have a registration system on my website.

However because my website is **Dutch**, I'd like to change the `url` from `localhost:8000/login` to `localhost:8000/inloggen` and the same for register.

Does anyone know if this is possible and how to do this?

I couldn't find anything on Google about this so that's why I'm asking here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add this in `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::get('/inloggen', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm' );
Route::post('/inloggen', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
```

You can find all `Auth::routes` here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1144

Answer (score 3):

Just remove `Auth::routes();` from your `routes/web`, And write auth routes manualy.

Here is default auth routes list.
[image]

You can write your own route for each of them. For example:

```
Route:post('inloggen', 'Auth\LoginController@login')
Route::get('inloggen', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
// And other auth routes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aliasing for routes to accomplish this:

```
Route::get('/inloggen',['as'=>'login','uses'=>'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm']);

Route::post('/inloggen',['as'=>'login','uses'=>'Auth\LoginController@login']);
```

Comment: `as` define the name of the route, not the URI. Title is confusing, but @max want to change the URI.

Comment: @cbaconnier what is confusion in this?we are just proving alias to the route

Comment: It doesn't work like that. This only provide a name to the route that you can use with `PHP` but it doesn't change the URI or provide an *alias* to the URL. You can't access to `myurl.test/password.request` where `password.request` is the default `name` of the route.

Comment: @cbaconnier I have updated the answer.Please correct if there is any issue yet